# How to implement the same querying logic for both database and collections

Tags: java, sql

So far I've used [OrmLite](http://ormlite.com/)'s [QueryBuilder](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/QueryBuilder.html) for implementation of filtering logic in my project. However, necessity for applying the same filtering logic to objects in java collections has emerged. I could reimplement the logic and keep two separate implementations but it doesn't seem like a good idea. Another idea I had was inserting data from a collection to an embedded RDB like [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) but this solution is very inefficient. Then I tried [JoSQL](http://josql.sourceforge.net/), it seems promising, it's only about 10x slower than raw java code but it's no longer maintained.

Are there any better solutions?